# RESTful client - how to process an external link?

Tags: rest, hateoas

By RESTful best services there is the HATEOAS principle which told us that we should not allow the client to build resource URL-s. If we follow this principle, it will be pretty hard to share the current state of the client. For example if you have a REST service on the server, and you gets data via AJAX with a single page javascript client, then you will have 2 urls. One for the client state, and one for the result you got from the REST service. You can share only the client state with the use due to pushState... If somebody runs the client with a previously shared url, then her client won't know about the url of the REST service it should call, because the client cannot build URL-s, just receive from the REST service and utilize it.

For example:

- I browse the `http://my.client.com`
- the page gets the root resource from the `http://my.api.com`, and return a link
- the link contains the `http://my.api.com/users` url, with rel user collection
- after that the client displays a button with label: userlist
- I click on that button, the client get the data from the api, and prints the user list
- if I want to share the user list with my girlfriend, then I have to change the browser url from the client with pushState, for example from `http://my.client.com` to `http://my.client.com/users`
- after that I send that url to my girlfriend
- she copy-pastes that into her browsers address bar and presses enter. after that the client says a huge wtf, because - like John Snow - it knows nothing about what state that url means...

This problem can be solved, if we allow the client to build `GET http://my.api.com/users` from the url: `http://my.client.com/users`, but this won't be RESTful, because the client should not build api urls...

If I want to display a nested menu in the client, then that is another problem, because I don't want to send the whole menu tree in every answer. I could create a menu projection for every resource, or use the OPTIONS method, or a custom method to send that data, but that would be a pain in the back. This can be solved by following the `rel=up` links - got from the REST service - in series, but if I don't know from where should I follow, it will not work...

This problem occurs by google bots too...

How can I both solve this problem, and stay inside the boundaries of the HATEOAS principle?

Comment: What is the purpose of "my.client.com". Couldn't you just point your web browser at "my.api.com". You seem to be building two clients, the browser and a client service running some where. You are chaining clients. That seems to be reinventing the wheel. A web browser is already a HTTP client.

Comment: The REST service should be stateless, so I have to use a client to store the state... By a regular webapplication you were right, but this is a RESTful webservice...

Comment: So my.client.com/users is really a command to JavaScript on the single page web app, rather than a call to an external service. In that case the client JavaScript should rebuild its knowledge of the server based on that command. It should say the user wants the users, so I'll start at the root my.api.com, find the link to users, which may be /users or may be something else, do a GET on that resource and display it to the user. The URIs you use to give commands to the JavaScript running in the browser should have nothing to do with the URIs on the server.

Comment: Giving that URI (which isn't really a URI) to your girlfriend doesn't matter because when she enters it the JavaScript app will rediscover the resources of the server from the root. The URI should have meaning for the client only.

Comment: Okay, but how to rediscover, and how to identify, that the resource it is looking for is the `service/users`? For example if the resource is something deeply nested, it can take a lot of http calls to the service to find that... So in theory it should be done so, but in practice I don't know how to do that... :S Maybe we'll need a query language to find resources?

Comment: Hmm I thought about it. The client should not build the url, but it can store it, for example in the browsers address bar. So for example if the main content is about the `http://my.api/service/users/123?projection=full`, and the client knows, that the service root is located under the url: `http://my.api/service`, then I can store the part which was built by the service in the address bar, and share it with anybody. So in the address bar the `http://my.client/state/users/123?projection=full` will be displayed. I don't think this contradicts with the HATEOAS principle...

Comment: Btw this is not an universal way to share client states. It would be much better this way: `http://my.client?state={url:"/users/123?projection=full", rel: "...", etc...}`. So I think I should store the whole link - I clicked on - in the address bar, and maybe everything else about the current state. This does not conflict with the REST principles, but the url will be very ugly... I don't think there is easier way to export the state of the current client...

Comment: Hmm the best way to do this, and keep urls pretty is a shortlink service...

Comment: But create shortlink by every click can be very slow... One thing is sure, this should be solved in the client side, and it is allowed to solve this by serializing the current state. If we want to rediscover a resource, the best way to send its url to the websercice, and ask if it exists. The second best way to send information what is the resource about, and maybe the service can find it with much more effort...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Normally we don't want to share all of that information with anybody, so we cannot export all of that just the current page we are in.

There is nothing wrong with storing the whole resource on the client and then pushing it up to the server to change the state on the server. If you are worried your resources are getting too large though you could break the resources out a bit. So say you have an order resource and that needs to associate with an address. You don't need to put the address in the order resource, just a link to the address to use. The user can add or alter that address independently. So you might have something like

```
www.myapi.com/users/1234/shippingaddresses/default
```

And the client can PUT a new address to this resource. Then in the body of the order resource you can have a link to this resource

```
POST www.myapi.com/users/1234/orders
{
    ...order information...
    "shipping_address": "www.myapi.com/users/1234/shippingaddresses/default"
}
```

To be RESTful the client should not build that URL, it should have been given it by the server at some point in the recent past, possibly when the users is selecting which address to use. For example, in the previous step the client could have requested all addresses

```
GET www.myapi.com/users/1234/shippingaddresses
```

And presented the list of addresses to the user in a drop down list.

Comment: I think there was a misunderstanding. Yes, it is allowed to store and display resource states in the client. I meant we usually don't want to store all of that info in the browsers address bar. For example by browsing a catalog in a webshop, you want to have the current product id in the address bar (for copy-pasting, and sharing it as a link with somebody), but you don't want to have for example all details about what is in your cart currently, or your session id, personal information, etc... So we usually want to share only partial information about the state of the REST client...

Comment: The thing is though that the REST client shouldn't have any state independently to the server. The client pulls down state from the server, modifies it, and pushes it back. You shouldn't be sharing complex state between clients independently to the server. The very most you should share between clients is maybe a bookmark to the last resource you were looking at. All state should go through the server, if you have to share state you must push it to the server and have another client pull it down from the server. Copying state from client to client view things like complex URIs is a bad idea.

Comment: You are right about many things, so I remove my probably bad answer (don't have the patience to read it) and accept yours instead. It is a hard job to fix old posts of mine... :S